# Is "configuration" a reserved name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, reserved-words

I am creating a scaffold with name "configuration" but it doesn't work, displaying the error:

```
"undefined method `all' for ActiveSupport::Configurable::Configuration:Class"
```

I tried the same scaffold but with different name and all was ok.

I would like know -- is "configuration" a reserved name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Configuration`, because it is [already used in Rails](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/configuration).

Comment: -1 I just used it (see below).  As long as you don't capitalize it (and YonHaime shows it as lower case) it should be ok.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, Did you actually try to use it once you generated it?  Following the your procedure I get ` Configuration (call 'Configuration.connection' to establish a connection)` error when trying to use the Configuration model.